# Get the count of multiple columns and update the count

Tags: mysql

I have an assignment to update the count in a mysql database

This is what I tried:

```
update matchNew set counter =  (select first, last, city, state, 
count(*) AS count
GROUP BY first, last, city, state)
where id < 5
```

What I want it to do is update the counter column with the count of how many occurrences of first + last + city + state there are.

And then update the count column next to each row.

Also, what indexes would be ideal here, a composite index on first + last + city + state?

I get the following error message:
Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, operand should contain 1 column because you're updating 1 column (`counter`) but you're selecting multiple columns to refer to (`SELECT first, last, city, state, 
count(*) AS count`).. that's 5 columns. So MySQL is basically telling you, you should update 1 column using 1 column only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, doing an update with a derived calculation such as this may not be the best approach.  In that case, just doing a select or maybe creating a view might be a better idea.  If you must do an update, then using an update join is one possibility:

```
UPDATE matchNew m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT first, last, city, state, cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT first, last, city, state, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM matchNew
        GROUP BY first, last, city, state
    ) t
) m2
    ON m1.first = m2.first AND
       m1.last = m2.last AND
       m1.city = m2.city AND
       m1.state = m2.state
SET counter = cnt
where m1.id < 5;
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The table has 250 million rows so I am assuming this approach will take a long time even with a composite index?

Comment: Because you are doing a count query, MySQL basically has to handle every record, so an index might not help much.